# add space between character of string in python use "for" loops in python

Tags: python, string

I write this code but it does not work:

```
a=input('word: ')
for i in a:
    print(i,'')
```

what is the problem?

Comment: What is your expected output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, `print` inserts a linebreak at the end of the string. You have to change it:

```
a=input('word: ')
for i in a:
  print(i,end=' ')
```

Output for Input `Hello`:
`H e l l o`

Answer (score 1):

You should provide the expected output because now we have to assume what it is you are trying to achieve.

When using "abc" as input I am now assuming you want

```
a b c
```

instead of

```
a
b
c
```

The problem here is, with every loop you call the 'print' function which starts a new line automatically when you should format your output correctly before calling print.
Try this:

```
a=input('word: ')
s = ""
for i in a:
    s += i + " "
print(s)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try doing this

```
a=input('word: ')

def func(a):
    lst = list(a)

    return " ".join(lst)

print(func(a))
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually you didn't add space. Try this:

```
a=input('word: ')
for i in a:
    print(i,' ')
```